# Androidx and gradle feature errors after running update

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, androidx, react-native-camera

I returned to a react native project after about a month or two and updated the packages along with all the packaged. However, it seems that in the time since I worked on it there have been some major changes which is now preventing `react-native run-android` from completing and results in a list of errors which seem related to the camera module, gradle and androidx.

Apologies, I could not paste the error in the post as it exceeds the character limit.

https://hatebin.com/bvsjcldeby

After initializing a new project all seems well so it appears to be something wrong with the configuration of the project itself.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you mention your react-native version?

Answer (score 1):

Google moves from the Support Library to the AndroiX library. So the first one is deprecated.

RN 0.60.X migrates to AndroidX ans so should each of the dependencies that you use. 0.60.X is a major breaking change and the way to solve it could be very wide. You would need to check each of your modules or dependencies that you use and find if they upgrades to use AndroidX. There is also a workaround where you could use Jetifier, which is a tool that will migrate old dependencies to the new AndroidX imports however I found it a little buggy dependening on your project.

My 2 cents right now would be to go to 0.59.8 until all major dependencies have time to upgrade and release their updated versions. Otherwise I think it is too much work right now.

You can see more here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60

Comment: Many thanks for your help sfratini. I'll switch back and hold off in the meantime. Thanks again.